# Is this a feasible security measure for my retail iPod Touches?

Tags: ipod-touch, security, apple-store

I'm considering using several iPod Touch devices as mobile computers in a retail setting.
If I did do this, I'd have to provide some measure of security for them.  I'm thinking of using the retail anti theft towers.

I've found some [two inch by two inch stickers](http://www.demco.com/goto?blk330) that are designed for library books.  In theory all I'd need would be towers of the same frequency as the stickers.

The fourth generation [iPod Touch teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPod-Touch-4th-Generation-Teardown/3562/1#.T84y4LNYuu8) shows that the screen is easily lifted from the body of the device and shows an EMI shield covering the rest of the device.

[image]

Would it be possible to attach one of these stickers and still have the screen close flush against the body?  Would it sitting between the screen and the bulk of the device interfere with the ability of the detection tower to detect the sticker?  Would the sticker interfere with the performance/lifespan of the iPod Touch?

*Basically, is this a feasible security measure?*
If someone knows how Apple secures their [retail iPod touch/barcode scanners](http://ipclineapro.com/) that would also be very useful.

Comment: I don't know specifically about this model, but it is unlikely that there is enough empty thickness or flexibility to fit a sticker in any such device — that would be wasted space not used for battery life or external thinness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be better off looking for a sticker to put on top of your security sticker, and stick the sticker sandwich on the back of the device. Just use something that would be too *time consuming* to remove before trying to exit with the device, which would set off your alarm.  The theory being that by not hiding your effort to thwart a theft, you may deter the theft to begin with. Otherwise, it looks like a free iPod touch that nobody will notice is gone. I'd make it as obvious as possible that there's a thief detector installed on the device.

Also: read about [Find My iPod Touch](http://images.apple.com/ipodtouch/built-in-apps/find-my-ipodtouch.html)